# Computing the Jacobian of $\mathbf{x} \mapsto \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\dot{x}}$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, vector-fields, jacobian

I am trying to compute the following vector-by-vector derivative

$$ \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\mathbf{x}}\left(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\dot{x}}\right), $$

where $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{\dot{x}}$ are $n \times 1$ column vectors, $\mathbf{A}$ is a constant $n \times n$ matrix, and $\dfrac{\text{d}\mathbf{\dot{x}}}{\text{d}\mathbf{x}}$ is a known $n \times n$ matrix.

I try to solve this by switching to index notation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x_m}\left(A_{ij} x_j x_k A_{kl} \dot{x}_l\right)
&= A_{ij} \delta_{jm} x_k A_{kl} \dot{x}_l
+ A_{ij} x_j \delta_{km} A_{kl} \dot{x}_l
+ A_{ij} x_j x_k A_{kl} \frac{\text{d}\dot{x}_l}{\text{d}x_m} \\
&\Rightarrow \mathbf{A} \left(\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{\dot{x}}\right)
+ \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} \,\left(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{\dot{x}}\right)^T
+ \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A} \dfrac{\text{d}\mathbf{\dot{x}}}{\text{d}\mathbf{x}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Is this correct? I don't have much experience with this kind of thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed I think it is correct.
You can use differential to avoid index notations.

Denote first
$$
\phi(\mathbf{x})
=
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} (\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\dot{x}})
$$
where the term in bracket is a scalar
$ s
=\mathbf{x}^T (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\dot{x}})
= (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\dot{x}})^T \mathbf{x}
$

From here, it follows
$d\phi 
= s\cdot d(\mathbf{Ax}) + (\mathbf{Ax}) \cdot ds
= s\mathbf{A} d\mathbf{x} + (\mathbf{Ax}) \cdot ds
$

It remains to compute
$ds 
= (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\dot{x}})^T d\mathbf{x} +
\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A} d\mathbf{\dot{x}}
$.

Using
$d\mathbf{\dot{x}}
= \dfrac{\text{d}\mathbf{\dot{x}}}{\text{d}\mathbf{x}} 
d\mathbf{x}$, and reorgainzing everything, we end up with

$$
d\phi 
= \left[
s\mathbf{A} + 
(\mathbf{Ax})
(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\dot{x}})^T + 
\mathbf{Ax}
\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A}
\dfrac{\text{d}\mathbf{\dot{x}}}{\text{d}\mathbf{x}}   
\right]
d\mathbf{x}
$$
from which you easily obtain the vector derivative.